# DataTable Buttons - Custom

Tags: javascript, button, datatables

In my configuration of a datatable button i have this:

```
buttons:[{
  extend: 'csvHtml5',
  text: '<span class="blabel"><i class="fa fa-download">  </i></span><span class="btxt">Export table</span>',
  className: 'btn btn-labeled'
},
```

the result is this button:

```
<a class="btn btn-default buttons-csv buttons-html5 btn-labeled" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" href="#">
<span> ---> I wanna remove this
<span class="blabel">
<span class="btxt">Export table to CSV</span>
</span>
</a>
```

I wanna remove the external span and the buttons-csv buttons-html5 classes... what is the correct way to do this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try use:

Remove `span` tag

```
$('span:not([class])').contents().unwrap();
```

and remove `classs`

```
$('.buttons-csv.buttons-html5').removeClass('buttons-csv buttons-html5');
```

Comment: Thanks. I could remove classes, but not span

Comment: I updated my answer, I added `.contents()` before `.unwrap()`

Comment: You are welcome :) Kindly accept my answer, if it is the correct answer !